# Java how to prevent widget disposed error?

Tags: java, multithreading, widget, swt, dispose

When I'm closing the main window I'm getting an error because it's disposed. I'm trying to "filter out" (using a condition), but I can't get it to work.

```
if(!Display.getDefault().isDisposed()){
   Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
         View.tableViewer.refresh();
         setViewInfo();
      }
    });
}
```

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to
>   execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)  at
>   com.chriss.udp.Message.WRITE(Message.java:166)    at
>   com.chriss.udp.threads.ThreadConnect.run(ThreadConnect.java:55)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed

Comment: Looks like your `TableViewer` (not the `Display`) is disposed, since the Exception is thrown inside the `run` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask whether [Widget](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html) is disposed.

```
boolean isDisposed()
```

> Returns true if the widget has been disposed, and false otherwise.

You have not to check the display, because as long as the application is running it is not disposed.
You have to check the table or this.isDisposed() inside the runnable.

Please post the full stack trace. I thinl the problem is inside the runnable.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, look at my code. I'm checking if the Display shell is disposed or not, but it's not working, I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian When you close the window, the shell (_not_ the display) is disposed, and so is everything it contains, including the table. Depending on your other code, this could also run _before_ the shell is disposed. So the sensible thing to be would be to check if the table is disposed.